# struct which a HANDLE points to

Tags: c++, winapi, internals

I tried without success to find information about the structs that HANDLEs point to.
For example, CreateFile() returns a HANDLE (== void*) that **I think** points to a struct with information about the file.
Same thing for processes and threads and every HANDLE.

So, where can I find information about the structs that the HANDLE points to?

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `HANDLE` type in WINAPI is an [opaque pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) utilized to hide implementation details from the programmer. It is usually a bad idea to write code that depends on the internals behind an opaque pointer since one of its uses is the ability for the API provider to change those internals without breaking any user code. Even if you find a way to read/write data behind them, it is not impossible for a new OS update to invalidate your software.

Comment: What you wrote is correct, and it is a good answer for *a* question, but not OP's question.

Comment: Hey, thanks for you answer, but it doesn't really answer what i asked...

I know that it is not a "good idea" to depend on the internals, but still I am looking for a way to "mess around" and play a little bit with the internals and I got stuck with it.

Answer (score 2):

The `HANDLE` is just a number that is used inside the kernel to lookup data (maybe in a tree or hash table) about the object. It is *not* a pointer. In order to learn about the object, you have to use a kernel-mode debugging tool. If that's what you're looking for, please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: I think that this is closest to answering OP's question, but you need to explain more what you mean by a `HANDLE` "is not a pointer". This implies that the Windows kernel reinterprets a `HANDLE` (a `typedef` of `PVOID`) as an integer. Do you have a reference to support this claim?

Comment: @Daniel: Unfortunately, this is something I read in Mark Russinovich's Windows Internals (a book). If you read his blog post, http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/09/29/3283844.aspx, you can get some details about how handle tables are laid out in the kernel.

Comment: HANDLE is not a pointer?! so why use void* and not int or long or longlong ?!

Thanks for the link I'll I think it will get me going :-)

Comment: @strDisplayName: It's idiomatic to use `void*` as a type for data that you're not supposed to care about. Being a pointer, it gets to be 64 bits on a 64-bit OS and you don't have to worry about its bits getting mangled by conversion between signed and unsigned fields or integers of different sizes. It's `void` because it doesn't mean anything (i.e. it's a token rather than an actual pointer).

Comment: In addition there are *many* structures that could back a handle - a handle to a file has a very different structure from a handle to a shared memory region.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access the internals of the struct - it may not even exist in your process. This is the point of using HANDLEs- so that you can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about Windows handles here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724485(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)