# What are handles for? IntPtr

Tags: c#, .net, handle, intptr

I have been reading up on IntPtr and have read that it is used to represent a Handle(s). What does this mean exactly? I'm sure it is a simple explanation, but the light bulb is just not turning on at the moment..

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148177/just-what-is-an-intptr-exactly

Comment: @Habjan: Not quite. The OP is asking about handles, whereas that question is asking about `IntPtr`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [struct which a HANDLE points to.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343660/struct-which-a-handle-points-to)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is typically referring to an operating system Handle, and used internally.  For example, Windows Forms uses an `IntPtr` to refer to the Control's native Window Handle (HWND).

Handles in the Windows API are used for many things - most operating system related resources (files, sockets, windows, etc) are all exposed through a handle, which is effectively a pointer.  In managed code, this gets stored in an `IntPtr`.

That being said, `IntPtr` is also regularly used to store pointers in interop scenarios, as well, as it automatically resizes based on 32bit or 64bit code.

Comment: +! for the use of HWND which is most often used in Windows API methods.  This honestly is a really good answer.

Answer (score 6):

A "handle" is an "opaque pointer". It's a value (usually just a number that's an index into an  array) that the operating system gives to an application to represent an internal object, instead of giving it a pointer to the actual object. This is both for safety and abstraction reasons -- it forces the application to use the handle only through the provided APIs.